# Tensorboard Invalid response: 500 Internal Server Error in Jupyterlab

Tags: docker, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

Im running a pod in Jupyterlab from a Docker image. The Docker image is based on the official `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0-py3` image, and I installed every depenencies as described [here](https://github.com/chaoleili/jupyterlab_tensorboard).

Whenever I try to launch Tensorboard, I get:

```
'Launcher Error Invalid response: 500 Internal Server Error'
```

[image]

Any idea on this? Im on Jupyter notebook 6.0.2
Everything else works fine.

Thanks

Comment: What do the logs of the container show when this occurs? `docker logs -f <container>`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is mentioned in this github issue https://github.com/chaoleili/jupyterlab_tensorboard/issues/25.

This is likely due to some recent refactoring of Tensorflow. More specifically, the removal of `TensorBoardWSGI`. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/3643.

Currently, the easiest way to fix it will be to use a lower version of Tensorboard. The latest version where `TensorBoardWSGI` is available is 2.2.

```
pip install tensorboard==2.2
```

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Make sure your run the tensorboard commands in the **System terminal** (with the `sagemaker-user@studio` user) and not in your Kernel/Notebook terminal.