# AWS Sagemaker Studio: Tensorboard fails to launch with "500: Internal Service Error" message

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

While training a model on Sagemaker Studio, I wanted to track some scalars using tensorboard but ran into a jupyter error when trying to proxy to the tensorboard hosted by the sagemaker terminal. I followed these steps:

1. Opened terminal and ran `pip install tensorboard`
2. Executed tensorboard with `tensorboard --logdir tb_logs/`
3. Copy pasted sagemaker URL and replaced last bit with `/proxy/6006/`

Why is it failing to launch tensorboard on sagemaker?

Python version: `3.7.10`;
Tensorboard version: `2.5.0`;
Tensorflow version: `2.3.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorboard Invalid response: 500 Internal Server Error in Jupyterlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642383/tensorboard-invalid-response-500-internal-server-error-in-jupyterlab)

Comment: I already looked into that and it doesn't (installing tensorboard=2.2). What's weird is that it worked a few days ago when I tried the exact same thing so I'm not sure why it's not working...